# Customized build and modules references in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm working on an application using typescript. The code of my app is designed as follows:

[Solution's Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rQVW.png)

I've two questions:

- How to build one .js file per module? Today I've one project per module, so the VS2013 build one .js file per module but I don't know if this approach is the best available.
- How to reference the modules on the GlobalAppModule, if I put the references in TypeScript directly, VS2013 build the code of one module in another's.

My original idea was to have only one project in my solution and create a build script to build which module to his own .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler should output one JavaScript file for each input TypeScript source file.  If you are seeing all your TypeScript source get combined into one JavaScript file per project, could you please check the project properties, and on the "TypeScript Build" tab ensure that "Combine JavaScript output into file" is not checked (this maps to the "--out" command-line parameter).

To reference files across projects, you can either:

1. Reference the code directly via "/// " tags.  This will however pull that referenced code into the compilation, which may not be desirable across projects.
2. Choose to "Generate declaration files" for the build of the project to reference ("--declaration" on the command-line).  This will create a "*.d.ts" file describing the types in the project.  You can then reference this declaration file in the other project (which will cause all the types to appear and be accessible, but won't pull in the actual source from the other project).

I hope this helps.